# Financial advisor is outperforming Vg LifeStrategy 80. Should I keep him?

Tags: investing, index-fund, vanguard

My financial advisor has my money invested in a range of actively managed funds.

In 4 years since July 2011, the portfolio he has created has gained about 50%, while LS 80 Acc has gained about 40%, all after going costs.

His charges on top of the ongoing costs are 0.42% for the platform plus 2% for him.

Everything I have learnt about active vs passive tells me that I should transfer my money into simple, cheap index trackers. Yet I am better off now due to active managers.

I am conflicted. Can someone offer me advice?

P.S. Here are the seven biggest holdings compared to LS 80 Acc: [image]

Comment: Please explain down votes?

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the chart comparing LS80 to the S&P -

[image]

Both have dividends not reflected in these returns. After adding 10% or so, the S&P during these 5 years was +55% or a bit more. As a result, the advisor lags the S&P by about 1% which makes sense.

One of the problems with the nature of the question is not being able to analyze the portfolios, your's vs the VG80, for risk-adjusted return. The return your advisor got you is great if the risk (volatility) is lower than the funds or indexes you're comparing to.

In the end, 4 years may not be long enough to make a proper comparison.

Comment: At least there's no obvious reason to jettison him yet. However: when comparing results, remember to subtract the management/transaction costs, which these charts don't always reflect. Paying (eg) 1.5% more in fees to get a 1% better return rate is _not_ an improvement!

Comment: @keshlam - agreed. But ironically, if the guy returned 100% over that time, it would also be a red flag. The period was a rising market, he has no track record with this client in a down one.